# Problems with CUDA 10.1 on K40c

Tags: pytorch, nvidia

I am using PyTorch on a K40c GPU. I install PyTorch using conda with the following command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

The installation goes smoothly. However, I have problems when I run cuda prpgrams. Here is a minimum example:

```
import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.version.cuda)
x = torch.tensor(1.0).cuda()
y = torch.tensor(2.0).cuda()

print(x+y)
```

The output is:

```
True
10.1.243
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(x+y)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

I have driver version 418.74. Following is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.74       Driver Version: 418.74       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K40c          On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| 23%   39C    P8    23W / 235W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

It looks like PyTorch correctly detects GPU and cuda, but fails when doing actual computation.

Comment: current versions of pytorch are built without support for cc3.5 devices.  See [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-1-2-0-with-compute-capability-3-5/53916/1)

Comment: @RobertCrovella Would be better if you put your comment as an answer.